# PHP fixed width image query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to rewrite this query for a wordpress site to force the thumbnail images to be displayed at 200px x 200px, the actual image sizes are about 300x300.

```
 <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>
```

I've tried rewriting the image loop to:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo '<img src="'. get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog').'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>
```

But this displays the path to the image, rather than the image itself.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You rewrite the image loop but it seems you still set it to 300x300? get_the_post_thumbnail has the following parameters: get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); maybe you could just set the size from there. (e.g. get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array(200,200) ));)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by resizing the image in the CSS. Doh!

```
#posts img{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Thanks